# Create MVC querystring from a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string, model-binding

Is it possible to, in code, to generate a querystring that will be binded to a controller variable like this

```
MyController(List<long?> queryList)
{
```

//I want the queryList to be bound using the defualt model binder.  But I don't know how to generate the source string that would be accepted here
    }

In my code, I need to generate the querystring in a function like this

```
GenerateBindable(List<long?> list)
{
    string listQueryString="";
    ....
    //What do I need to do here?
}
```

I was trying to find a built-in function for this, but even the ActionLink helper did not do what I expected.  It resulted in this

My/URL/PATH?a=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Nullable%601%5BSystem.Int64%5D%5D

Seems like it just did a ToString on the collection, which obviously won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a route value dictionary in your controller.

```
var rv = new RouteValueDictionary();
int i = 0;
queryList.ForEach(t => { rv.Add("a[" + (++i) + "]", t); });
```

Lets say you add this route value dictionary to the viewbag (or your model).  I'm going to use the viewbag for demonstration purposes but I always recommend you use a model instead.

```
ViewBag.RouteValues = rv;
```

Finally in your view just create an action link using the route value dictionary.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", (RouteValueDictionary)ViewBag.RouteValues)
```